Keep the connection open in Microsoft Practices EnterpriseLibrary to run multiple SPs
We are using EnterpriseLibrary  to connect to database. I want run 2 or more SPs on same connection. I want set the context and run multiple SPs in the same session.
But when the first SP the the connection is getting closed.
 db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
 DbCommand selectCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.usp_set_session_context");
 db.ExecuteReader(selectCommand);


 DbCommand selectCommand1 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.usp_get_session_context");
 using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(selectCommand1))
 {
     while (dataReader.Read())
     {
         var data = dataReader["LoginUserAccountName"].ToString();
        
     }
 }

I did tried open a connection and tried to use it but its not working as well
//using (var con = db.CreateConnection())
//{
//    con.Open();
//    DbCommand selectCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.usp_set_session_context");
//    db.ExecuteReader(selectCommand);


//    DbCommand selectCommand1 = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.usp_get_session_context");
//    using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(selectCommand1))
//    {
//        while (dataReader.Read())
//        {
//            var data = dataReader["LoginUserAccountName"].ToString();
//           
//           
//        }
//    }
//}

How can I keep my connection alive? I don't want to use the transition scopes.

I specifically mentioned I don't want to use transitions. some one still thought its duplicate please read

Its been long since I worked in MS Enterprise Library DAAB, can you see if this fixes your issue
DbCommand selectCommand = = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.usp_set_session_context");
DbCommand selectCommand1 = = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.usp_get_session_context");

using (DbConnection connection = db.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        // Credit the first account.
        db.ExecuteReader(selectCommand);
        IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(selectCommand1);
        while (dataReader.Read())
         {
             var data = dataReader["LoginUserAccountName"].ToString();
         }
    }
    catch
    {
        // do any logging here
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}


Unfortunately its not working.
